# Authlogic and Rails 4 - "current_user is undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I've implemented Authlogic in my Rails 4 app.  I can connect to my LDAP server and authenticate with my AD username and password.  But, I cannot call "current_user" anywhere in the app.

For instance, when I call  `Welcome, <%= current_user.first_name %>`

I get:  `undefined method 'first_name' for nil:NilClass`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  helper :all
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

  private
    def current_user_session
      return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
      @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

    def current_user
      return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
      @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
    end

end
```

Any ideas are appreciated.  Thanks!
Katie

Comment: I didn't see this comment yesterday, sorry. I'm not sure I understand - where would I define UserSession.find?  I know Authlogic isn't completely ready for Rails 4, but it does bind to LDAP successfully, so I would think a session would bind, as well, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authlogic, as of today, is not ready for Rails 4:

http://ready4rails4.net/

Name:   authlogic
Status: not ready
Notes:  [pull request](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/pull/368)

Comment: Oh, well that explains it!  Thanks.  I'm glad it's kinda working.  :)

Comment: I think this answer should be deleted, as authlogic is now ready for rails4, and has been for a year.

Answer (score 3):

Authlogic is working for my Rails 4 app. current_user works just fine. You may want to try it again.

Comment: Yeah, it was working the whole time.  The problem was I created my user account in the database, not through the app, so I didn't have a session token!  DUH.  When I created the record correctly, all was good.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Authlogic is now working. if there are issues, provide the following in your gemfile:

> gem 'authlogic', github: 'binarylogic/authlogic', ref: 'e4b2990d6282f3f7b50249b4f639631aef68b939'

Answer (score 0):

@rhuppert, that particular authlogic commit really saved my bacon, thank you for sharing that information. Turns out the newer Authlogic versions, 3.3.0 and 3.4.0, no longer work with one of my Rails 4.0.x apps, but when I use the version you mention (**gem 'authlogic', github: 'binarylogic/authlogic', ref: 'e4b2990d6282f3f7b50249b4f639631aef68b939'**) it works with Rails 4.0.x. The error I was getting with both Authlogic 3.4.0 and 3.8.0 was (line from Rails logger):

```
F, [2014-03-04T07:25:09.640105 #28602] FATAL -- : NameError (uninitialized constant SCrypt):
  app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

Thanks again!